# Meraki and custom splash page for authorization

Tags: php, wifi, cisco, access-point

I am trying to create custom authorization splash screen for Meraki Cloud Wi-Fi (https://meraki.cisco.com). I've created splash page successfully as described here: https://documentation.meraki.com/MR/Splash_Page/Configuring_a_Custom-Hosted_Splash_Page_to_work_with_the_Meraki_Cloud

Everything is ok, but I see one major problem: how I can force user do something for getting wi-fi access, if user simple can pick `base_grant_url` from redirected url and get access to requested site?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: No, I've get rid from meraki :)